# Passing data to SOAP web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have created a web service and deplyed it on GlassFish on localhost.

```
@WebService
public class ProductCatalog {
  ProductServiceImpl productService = new ProductServiceImpl();
  public boolean addProductCategories(String category) {
    return productService.addCategory(category);
  }
  public List<String> getProductCategories() {
    return productService.getCategories();
  }
}
```

My service class

```
public class ProductServiceImpl {
    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    public boolean addCategory(String categoryName) {
        return categories.add(categoryName);
    }
    public List<String> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }
}
```

Through the GF admin panel I checked both methods. They work. I can add a category or get all existing categories.

After that I imported the wsdl and got following classes.

[image]

Then I created a new project and added imported classes to it.

```
public class DataController {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String category = "Horror";
    ProductCatalog productCatalog = new ProductCatalog() {
      public boolean addProductCategories(String arg0) {
        return false;
      }

      public List<String> getProductCategories() {
        return null;
      }
    };

    productCatalog.addProductCategories(category);

    ProductCatalogService productCatalogService = new ProductCatalogService();
  }
}
```

Now I wan't to add a new category, but have no idea how to do it.

This

```
productCatalog.addProductCategories(category);
```

doesn't work. The app runs, but when checking existing categories through GF admin panel, I see that none were added.

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong way. This is how it should be.

```
public class DataController {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String category = "Anime";
    ProductCatalogService productCatalogService = new ProductCatalogService();
    ProductCatalog productCatalog = productCatalogService.getProductCatalogPort();
    productCatalog.addProductCategories(category);
    List<String> categories = productCatalog.getProductCategories();
    for(String categoryName : categories){
      System.out.println(categoryName);
    }
  }
}
```